# error on get object json value from array query

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a problem with javascript json. I can get the value from ajax post.

The Script Like this.

```
<script> function makeAjaxCall()
{ 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "post", 
        data: $('#form1').serialize(), 
        url: "http://localhost/SPKM/new_file.php", 
        cache: false,   
        success: function(json){        
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json); 
        var r = obj['STATUS'];
        alert(r);
    } 
});
} 
</script>
```

and The form like this..

```
<form name="form1" id="form1">
<input type="text" name="value" id="value">
<input type="button" name="Submit" onkeypress="makeAjaxCall()">
</form>
```

And The new_file.php like this..

```
<?
$query = "SELECT sum(in)-sum(out) AS total FROM $tableName";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   { 
   $phpVar = array("STATUS",$row['total']));
   echo json_encode($phpVar);
   }
?>
```

The result is undefined when i click the button..
Thanks for the help..

Comment: your closing quote (") is missing in SELECT query..?

Comment: $phpVar = array("STATUS",$row['total'])); Missing =>
array('STATUS' => $row['total'])

Comment: no Sudhir, I have problem on  $phpVar = array("STATUS",$row['total'])); echo json_encode($phpVar); and var r = obj['STATUS'];

Comment: DevMetal, in this project i m not use code igniter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That undefined, because you array is not associative map.

```
<?php
$array = array('status' => $row['total']);
?>
```

Comment: oh yeah,, thanks alot.. the answer in =>.. thanks alot DevMetal91

Answer (score 2):

You array will be of structure

```
[0] => "STATUS"
[1] => somevalue
```

As you can see there is no index "STATUS", so `obj['STATUS']` will return you undefined. Either add `=>` in your array creation or take the 1st index of obj.

Answer (score 0):

js

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "post", 
    data: $('#form1').serialize(), 
    url: "http://localhost/SPKM/new_file.php", 
    cache: false,   
    success: function(json){
        console.log( json.STATUS );
    }
});
```

php

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo json_encode(array(
        "STATUS"=> $row['total']
    ));
}
```